# SQLite.Net.SQLiteException: "too many SQL variables" (UWP)

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, uwp

Добрый день!

Не могу понять и побороть причину исключения SQLite.Net.SQLiteException: **"too many SQL variables"**. Проект UWP на C#. Используется библиотека SQLite.Net.
Исключение выбрасывается при вызове метода **SQLiteConnection.UpdateWithChildren(object item)**.
Ниже представлен скриншот исключения и содержимое query.

[image: Скриншот исключения и содержимое query]
Исключение срабатывает на довольно большом объекте для обновления. Скриншот содержимого представлен ниже.

[image: Скриншот содержимого объекта]

Прошу помочь разобраться в этой проблеме и решить ее.
С нетерпением жду ваш ответ!

Comment: *Не могу понять и побороть причину исключения* - вам перевести с английского?

Comment: Мн ни о чем не говорит "слишком много SQL переменных". Я использую SQLite.Net, и что с этим делать не понимаю вообще.

Answer (score 3):

**SQLite** по умолчанию **имеет ограничение** на передачу **999** переменных, но его можно изменить во время выполнения запроса. Если выпадает такое исключение, значит, скорее всего, установлено дефолтное значение.

---

Пример изменения лимита:

```
sqlite3_limit(db,SQLITE_LIMIT_VARIABLE_NUMBER,size)
```

---

Что делать - описано [тут](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_limit_attached.html#sqlitelimitvariablenumber).

Об ограничениях можно прочитать [тут](https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html).

Comment: От чего зависит превышение этого лимита? Если мой объект станет больше, то я снова могу превысит лимит?

Comment: Можно менять лимит в зависимости от потребностей. Вопрос только в целесообразности. Почитайте документацию, не поленитесь

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что если у меня есть объект с 10 переменными, то 1000 таких объектов дадут мне 10.000 SQL variables?

Comment: Я вижу, что объект item, для которого я делаю UpdateWithChildren содержит 1108 элементов. И в query попадает 1108 переменных ("?"). А что с этим делать, собственно? Количество этих объектов может быть и 3000 и 10.000, следовательно и переменных будет больше, числом конкретным это не выразить.

Comment: В момент выполнения запроса это количество может быть точно определено? Если да, то ставьте соответствующий лимит, либо определитесь с максимально возможным количеством и сделайте это один раз

Comment: А вообще - этот вопрос лучше адресовать [разработчикам](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) nuget пакета, возможно такой или подобный issue там уже заведён